# center only icons (not text also) horizontally and vertically on a button

Tags: android, xml

I have 3 buttons at the bottom of an app im creating, and I'm just trying to use some stock android icons instead of text or a combination of both. There is the `andoid:drawableStart / top / bottom / etc` commands but I just would like these icons to appear smack dab in the middle. There seems to be no easy solution for this? Here is what I am working with:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/calm"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".PiktuurMain" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/takepic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/round" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editpic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/round" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sharepic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use `CTRL+SHIFT+F` in `XML` for formatting ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html):

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sharepic"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `MaterialButton`. It has more advantages than something else. like the ripple effect, theme, icon tint, shape appearance, and so on.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_sports_soccer_24"
    app:iconPadding="0dp" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_sports_soccer_24" />
```

[image]

Also, you should set `android:padding="Xdp"` to get suit width.

Comment: Best answer to get a simple icon only material button. Thanks! :)

Comment: If you put `minWidth="0dp"` you are not having the min widht and height of 48dp.

Answer (score 1):

You can used `ImageButton` instead `Button`. below i show you **footer** layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/trans_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ib_add_ed_lay"
            style="@style/Bottombar2LinearLayout" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_add"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/add_event_button_back" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ib_map_ed_lay"
            style="@style/Bottombar2LinearLayout" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_map"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/map_button_back" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ib_call_cd_lay"
            style="@style/Bottombar2LinearLayout" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_get_route"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/route_button_back" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Add `style` in `values\styles.xml`

```
 <style name="Bottombar2LinearLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">1dp</item>
</style>
```

**Output:** [image]

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, Material Design's [icon buttons](https://m3.material.io/components/icon-buttons/overview) are the convenient way to do this.
Just include one of the appropriate styles and provide the icon.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLike"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.IconButton.Outlined"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_heart_outline" />
```

[image: screenshot from resulted button]